# Stop SWF file from repeating

Tags: flash, repeat

I have converted a short clip to an .swf file, i want to implement it on my website:

```
<object width="400" height="300">
<param name="movie" value="movie.swf">
<embed src="movie.swf" width="400" height="300">
</embed>
</object>
```

When i play it it autoplays (that's fine) but it also keeps repeating over and over, i'd like it to stop at the end and just display the end frame (as mentioned i converted a movie so i cant do it with actionscript in the .fla file).
Thanks for any tips!

Comment: How did you convert clip? What software was used?

Comment: Xilisoft movie converter - it's a free program

Answer (score 0):

Try adding
`<param name="loop" value="false">` after the other param
and `loop="false"` within the embed tag.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html